# DRF serializer field renamed to it's source in validated data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a drf serializer with a field I would like to rename:

```py
class UserBulkUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    is_admin = serializers.BooleanField(required=False, source='administrator')
```

However, in `validated_data` attribute it's got renamed back to the `source` attribute value. I'm doing this:

```py
serializer = UserBulkUploadSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
return serializer.validated_data
```

And there's no `is_admin` key in there, it's `administrator`.

Is there a way to overcome this and make it `is_admin` in `validated_data`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've digged into DRF sources and seems there's no clean solution for this.
`validated_data` attribute just not designed to handle this.
`data` attribute will have the output with renamed keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to add two fields, one write-only field, and one read-only field.
Like this:

```
class UserBulkUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    administrator = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    is_admin = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True, source='administrator')

    extra_kwargs = {
        'administrator': {'write_only': True},
    }
```

I haven't been able to test this one yet, so I'm not sure if two fields with the same source will cause errors, otherwise you could change is_admin to a SerializerMethodField.

Comment: Yeah, I've already done some hack like this just replacing the key programmatically but I'm wondering if I'm missing something about serializers fields and if it can be fixed in some clean way.

Comment: In my example in the question I have `administrator` field in the incoming data:  
`serializer = UserBulkUploadSerializer(data=data)`  
and I want it to be translated to `is_admin` in serializer output. So providing `source` attribute feels like a logical way to implement this, but it doesn't work as I expect it to ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Wait, I am very confused right now. The field is called administrator on incoming data, it is called administrator on your model, but you want it to be called is_admin on outgoing data? Or is it called is_admin on your model as well?

Comment: It's `administrator` on the model and I want it to be called `is_admin` on the outgoing data

Comment: Is it called administrator on incoming data? Or are you not using it for incoming data?

Comment: Yes, It's called administrator on the incoming data, which I don't want to manipulate either. I want the serializer to have it's output different from the input

Comment: You can check my updated answer, if you're still having trouble, I could help you out in the chat.

Comment: Providing read only and write only field didn't change anything. Providing renamed field as `SerializerMethodField` adds `is_admin` key as I wanted but `administrator` key is still there which is not the case for me too. I've digged deeper and seems figured out the answer - `validated_data` field is just doesn't deal with renaming by design. Thank you for your help & effort!